# Octave not recognizing installed packages

Tags: octave

My newly installed Octave is not recognizing installed packages:

```
>> pkg install -forge quaternion
For information about changes from previous versions of the quaternion package, run 'news quaternion'.
>> pkg list
no packages installed.
>>
```

I'm using Octave-4.0.3 on Windows 10. The install operation updates the appropriate files under `c:\Octave\Octave-4.0.3\share\octave\packages\` and `c:\Octave\Octave-4.0.3\lib\octave\packages\`. An install from local file (not using `-forge`) produces the same results.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Cap. How did you install octave? The [windows installer provided](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/octave-4.0.3-installer.exe) seems to come with all important packages preinstalled! Did you use something else?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce this on Octave-4.0.3 on my windows 10. I even uninstalled and reinstalled `quaternion` from forge. Everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

This was a usage problem on my part. I had defined a function called `load` which shadowed the built-in function of the same name and prevented `pkg` from working correctly.

Unfortunately there is not a warning that a built-in is being shadowed as you add it, but I saw the warning when changing the current working directory away from and then back to the one where I had the function stored. Tip for Octave beginners like me: Before you write a function with a generic name, check first if a function with that name already exists (eg with `help functionName`)!

Comment: I would encourage you to submit a bug to the octave bug tracker; it's a silly bug, but a bug nonetheless; the pkg command is central to octave and should have been immune to even such a silly scenario.

Comment: @Tasos: Thanks for your help. I've submitted the feature request #48845 https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?48845